# Is there a way for me to use a dictionary values to loop through a string?

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

What I'm trying to do here is change the values in the dictionary and then use the dictionary so that it loops through the string's elements so that it'll reflect for every instance of a key. Do any of you have a recommendation on what to do next? I think I need to set up a loop, but am unsure of what to do. Thank you.

```
string = 'abdcabdcadcbacb'
b = 12
dict = {'a': 50,  'b': 40,  'c': 30, 'd': 20}
for aa in dict.keys(): 
    dict[i] -= b 
#output should be 360
```

Edit: I also need to return the sum of the difference once it's looped through the string. The output should be 360, sorry for not making it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need.

```
string = 'abdcabdcadcbacb'
b = 12
d = {'a': 50,  'b': 40,  'c': 30, 'd': 20}
for i in string: 
    if i in d:
        d[i] -= b
print(d)  # {'a': 2, 'b': -8, 'c': -18, 'd': -16}
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use reserved words as variable names.
In your code, you have used dict as a variable name which is a reserved keyword.

```
string = 'abdcabdcadcbacb'
b = 12
dictionary = {'a': 50,  'b': 40,  'c': 30, 'd': 20}
for i in dictionary.keys():
    dictionary[i]-=b
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have remembered that!

Comment: Seems you modified your answer after posting the [third](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67136347/5929910) answer. No offense post another way you have

Comment: ya I understood the exact question of what he is looking for. Sorry and Thanks

Comment: Oh I see, I should have made a new post. I am completely new but I should have done so anyways. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to modify your dictionary first by subtracting your dictionary value with `b`. Then you expect the sum by iterating your string. If any character of the string matches to dictionary key then sum it.

```
string = 'abdcabdcadcbacb'
b = 12
sum = 0
my_dict = {'a': 50,  'b': 40,  'c': 30, 'd': 20}
for k in my_dict.keys():
    my_dict[k] -= b
for s in string:
    if s in my_dict.keys():
        sum += my_dict[s]
print(sum)
```

**Output**

```
360
```

Comment: Thank you! Would there be something I need to change if the values in my_dict happened to be floats instead of integers?

Comment: Will work accordingly but shouldn't change any modification after posting a specific question

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I should have made a new one.